# Can Active Directory Upgrade lead to problems with SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, security, active-directory

Are there compatibility issues between SharePoint version and Active Directory version?

I have a scenario with MOSS 2007 and Active Directory 2000.

I will upgrade Active Directory to 2012.

I could not find any information regarding any compatibility issues. Would the two items be compatible please?

Answer (score 3):

It's not supported to install Moss 2007 on Windows Server 2012, but you might be able to link them as stated on MSDN forum in this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5559885a-db83-4141-9719-422f45d323e4/moss-2007-and-active-directory-windows-server-2012-are-they-compatible?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy) e.g. domain controller on another server if that helps.

[SharePoint Server 2007 is not supported Windows Server 2012](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2728964)

Comment: Thanks, the article does not specify whether linking to AD 2012 is supported. I would assume yes, but it may be better if I test it out first...

Comment: @JosephCaruana yup that's right but my assumptions were based on another post answered by a MVP on MSDN forum, please check updated answer.